# Rails rollback while saving model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a license server, but I stuck with problem, that Rails can't save model.

I set `after_create` method in `User` model, but got no luck, also I tried create `License` model with Rails console, but it rollback transaction and didn't show any error.

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
     authentication_keys: [:login]

  attr_writer :login
  has_one :license, dependent: :destroy

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates_format_of :username, with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$/, multiline: true

  after_create :create_assocs

  def login
    @login || self.username
  end

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(['lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value', { value: login.downcase }]).first
    else
      if conditions[:username].nil?
        where(conditions).first
      else
        where(username: conditions[:username]).first
      end
    end
  end

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  private

  def create_assocs
    create_license(license_types_id: LicenseType.first.id)
    # license = License.new(user_id: self.id, license_types_id: 1)
    # license.save
    # self.license.create(license_types_id: LicenseType.first.id)
  end
    end
```

**models/license.rb**

```
class License < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :license_type
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :set_expired_at

  private

  def set_expired_at
    # self.expired_at = DateTime.now + self.license_types.duration
  end
end
```

in rails console,

```
2.5.1 :001 > license = License.new(license_types_id: LicenseType.first.id)
  LicenseType Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "license_types".* FROM "license_types" ORDER BY "license_types"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<License id: nil, expired_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, license_types_id: 1, user_id: nil> 
2.5.1 :002 > license.save
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
 => false
```

**schema.rb**,

```
  create_table "licenses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "expired_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "license_types_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["license_types_id"], name: "index_licenses_on_license_types_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_licenses_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: ""
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.string "key"
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "licenses", "users"
```

What should I do to set the license for new user after creating?

Comment: You will create objects through controller only so you should provide controller code so it will clear idea how to provide association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

License model contains two foreign key `user_id` and `license_type_id`

=> Which means before create `License` there must be a user who own this `License` as Rails 5 convention says `user_id` must exist

=> Also there must exist `LicenseType` as Rails 5 convention says `license_type_id` must exist

The rollback reasons can be investigated by following

```
license = License.new(license_types_id: LicenseType.first.id)
license.save
#Begin
#ROLLBACK
errors_stack = license.errors
```

`errors_stack` contains model level errors which causes rollback

To fix these rollback issue

```
user = User.first #or current_user
license = user.license.new(license_type_id: LicenseType.first.id)
license.save
```

Or

```
user = User.first #or current_user
license = License.new(license_type_id: LicenseType.first.id, user_id: user.id)
license.save
```

Or  To create a `User` and assign the user a `License` # Alternative of after_create :create_assocs

```
new_user = User.new(...)
new_user.license.build(license_type_id: LicenseType.first.id)
new_user.save
```

Comment: Ask OP to provide controller code, it will clear lot, but above will work anyhow well!

Comment: @3kpvc Glad to know that , you can try last line solution to overcome with `after_create`. hopefully that will be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about this "no errors"? In Rails 5, `belongs_to` association is required by default, so I guess that's because it fails (you don't set `user` association prior to save attempt). So either you should set `license.user`, or set:

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

in `License` model if your business logic doesn't require it.